# Simple contact form with alert mesage and without page refresh/load

Tags: forms, alert, contacts, contact-form

Can somenone show me how to make a simple contact form to send an e-mail to demo@mysite.com just with an edit form(let's call it "name") and after that verify that form has  min 10characters sends the e-mail and an alert box shows "E-mail send! Thank you"?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking about website form?

Comment: Yes.. For example i want to make a form like this http://demos.9lessons.info/contact/index.html but only with the "name" field and when you send the mail, it shows an alert box.